# Custom Validation code behind

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have a custom validation for the name field of my site. In the code behind is the code for it but it doesn't work. It does not give the error like the other validators do. this is my code.

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidatorVoorNaam" runat="server" ControlToValidate="voornaamTextBox" onServerValidate="naamValidator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Gebruik enkel het alfabet" ValidationGroup="AllValidators">Enkel A-Z</asp:CustomValidator>

protected void naamValidator(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    bool check = true;
    for (int i = 0; i > e.ToString().Length; i++)
    {
        if (!(char.IsLetter(e.ToString()[i])))
        {
            check = false;
        }
    }
    e.IsValid = check;
}
```

as far as I could find this is the correct code.

UPDATE

The error is shown when I enter it while leaving it empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess e.toString() is going to return the type of e as string, try using value instead

```
protected void naamValidator(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        bool check = true;
        for (int i = 0; i > e.Value.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (!(char.IsLetter(e.ToString()[i])))
            {
                check = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        e.IsValid = check;

    }
```

Comment: No, I have changed my code now. I call an method from another class. So my code now looks like this in the code behind file.

Comment: protected void CustomValidatorVoorNaam_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
        {
            args.IsValid = Validatie.ControleerNaam(args.ToString());

        }

Comment: are you re-using your validation among serveral custom validators?

Comment: not yet, it is a group project for school. A team member has made the class 'validatie' with several methods to check if names or psswords have illegal arguments in them. So I am planning to make 3 or so custom validators that will use the class 'validatie' in the code behind. I followed the tutorial and checked everything and it is correct.